# When can I expect an infant to be willing to stand?

Tags: infant, development, milestones

I'm worried about my granddaughter who is 3.5 months. She is not even wanting to use her legs to stand up when we try to make her stand.  But I can see when she's laying down she moves her legs, and when she's mad she kicks very strong.  Do we need to ask her doctor about this?

Comment: No harm asking her doctor whatever you want, but 3.5 months is very young.  At four months is when babies typically just start being able to hold up their heads when sitting up.  So I don't think it's time yet to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Three and a half months is much too early to be trying to stand up. Most babies don't start to stand up whilst holding something until around 7-9 months although they may be putting weight on their legs before then with help. 3.5 months is even very early for sitting up.

Here is a link for what you might expect babies to be doing at any particular age. "Can bear weight on legs" comes at 4 months but "stands while holding onto something" is listed as an advanced skill at 7 months

http://www.babycentre.co.uk/a6476/milestone-chart-one-to-six-months

Even so, all children develop at their own pace with their own strengths and weaknesses. Three and a half months seems way too soon to be putting pressure on a baby to be making any big achievements. Just enjoy your granddaughter while she is tiny - it doesn't last long!